# How to AutoFilter using IF conditions on VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, autofilter

I am really new to VBA and I got stuck on a filtering function that I cannot resolve looking online.

I basically built a login form which allows different users to see different data on a "Report sheet" once they log in. In the "Report sheet" I have two columns "P" and "Q" in which some names are reported.

Let's say:

```
P      Q
User1  User2

Paul   Bob
Martin Martin
Bob    Bob
Tom    Martin
Ralph  Bob
```

I then used this code on VBA:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Range("Report!$F$6:$Y$11").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:=Range("G3").Value

End Sub
```

**G3 is the reference cell for the name*

Now, if I login with Bob, using that code, the result will be:

```
P      Q
User1  User2

Paul   Bob
Bob    Bob
Ralph  Bob
```

That is correct! However, if I try to login with Paul, no result is available because he's not on the Field:=12 (column "Q").

I would like to do something like this: IF Paul is not on column "Q", stop filtering that column and start filtering column "P".

I tried with:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

If Range("Report!$F$6:$Y$11").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter(Field:=12, Criteria1:=Range("G3").Value) Then 'do nothing

Else
Range("Report!$F$6:$Y$11").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=11, Criteria1:=Range("G3").Value

End If

End Sub
```

but I don't really know what to state for positive results.

Thank you in advance to everyone that will help me on that.

Comment: `if application.worksheetfunction.countif(range("Q:Q"),range("g3").value)>0...`

Comment: Hi @Nathan_Sav, thanks for sharing it. I tried it, but unfortunately it gives me back run-time error 1004.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Find method of range to see if present

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim found As Range
    Set found = Worksheets("Report!").Range("$Q$6:$Q$11").Find(what:=Range("G3").Value, lookat:=xlWhole)

    If Not found Is Nothing Then
        ' Stuff with Field:=12, Criteria1:=Range("G3").Value)
    Else
      ' Stuff with Field:=11, Criteria1:=Range("G3").Value)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Remember to remove filtering first AutoFilterMode = False ; then if your code is only filtering one field at a time, only one filter should be applied. Field 11 or Field 12.